# Fluent ribbon tab item click event

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0, ribbon, fluent-ribbon

I am using the Fluent Ribbon and got stuck with this problem. I have added some ribbon tab items and wanted to execute something if the user clicks on them

```xml
<Fluent:RibbonTabItem Name="TabItem" MouseLeftButtonDown="TabItem_MouseLeftButtonDown">
    <Fluent:RibbonGroupBox Header="">
        <Fluent:Button/>
        <Fluent:Button/>
    </Fluent:RibbonGroupBox>
    <Fluent:RibbonGroupBox Header="">
        <Fluent:Button Name="General" Header="General" Click="General_Click" />
    </Fluent:RibbonGroupBox>
</Fluent:RibbonTabItem>
```

This is a simplified part of the code... however if i click on the General button the click event fires as expected but if i click the ribbon tab item nothing happens. Here are both event handlers

```
 private void TabItem_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        //some code        
    }

 private void General_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //more code           
    }
```

Does anyone know how to fire this event?

Comment: I am gonna post a workaround just in case someone has the same problem... I have just added a `Loaded` event to the first button in the groupbox so when the button is showen the code is executed... somehow dirty but it works...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's simpler than you think: the `Ribbon` class has a `SelectedTabChanged` event.

It is fired twice every time you change tab:

- the first time the `System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs` contains the old tab in `RemovedItems`
- the second time it contains the new tab in `AddedItems`.

Both those properties are an `object[]`.

Just look for it in the property window or let the IntelliSense find it for you ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try SelectionChanged event on Ribbon Object.